# Different ways of building a query in Joomla?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla1.6, joomla2.5

Just starting out, this should be a simple one but I haven't been able to find a good source, especially with the 1.5 to 1.6/1.7/2.5 changeover.

Building a component and among other issues keep running into syntax issues.

For example, here's one way I'm building a query:
**[TYPE 1]**

```
$query->SELECT('u.id as UserID
    , u.name AS Name
    , uppi.profile_value AS Hair
    , uppi2.profile_value AS Height
    ');
$query->FROM (' #__users AS u');
$query->LEFTJOIN (' #__user_profiles AS uppi ON u.id = uppi.user_id AND uppi.ordering = 1 ');
$query->LEFTJOIN (' #__user_profiles AS uppi2 ON u.id = uppi2.user_id AND uppi2.ordering = 2 ');
$query->GROUPBY (' u.id
    , u.name
    , uppi.profile_value
    ');
```

Another way:
**[TYPE 2]**

```
$query->SELECT('u.id as UserID
    , u.name AS Name
    , uppi.profile_value AS Hair
    , uppi2.profile_value AS Height
    ')
->FROM (' #__users AS u')
->LEFTJOIN (' #__user_profiles AS uppi ON u.id = uppi.user_id AND uppi.ordering = 1 ')
->LEFTJOIN (' #__user_profiles AS uppi2 ON u.id = uppi2.user_id AND uppi2.ordering = 2 ')
->GROUPBY (' u.id
    , u.name
    , uppi.profile_value
    ');
```

Confusing part about both of those is that mysql calls like "LEFTJOIN" are one word instead of two.  So then if I want to use `INSERT…ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` I'm totally lost.

Here's a third:
**[TYPE 3]**

```
$query->SELECT('u.id as UserID
    , u.name AS Name
    , uppi.profile_value AS Hair
    , uppi2.profile_value AS Height
    ');
$query->FROM (' #__users AS u');
$query->JOIN ('LEFT', ' #__user_profiles AS uppi ON u.id = uppi.user_id AND uppi.ordering = 1 ');
$query->JOIN ('LEFT', ' #__user_profiles AS uppi2 ON u.id = uppi2.user_id AND uppi2.ordering = 2 ');
$query->GROUPBY (' u.id
    , u.name
    , uppi.profile_value
    ');
$query->ORDER ('u.name ASC');
```

This is another way I've seen queries built but can't get to work [**EDITED** - working now, thanks @cppl!]
**[Type 4]**

```
$query= "SELECT `u`.`id` as UserID
    , `u`.`name` AS Name
    , `uppi`.`profile_value` AS Hair
    , `uppi2`.`profile_value` AS Height
FROM `#__users` AS u
LEFT JOIN `#__user_profiles` AS uppi ON `u`.`id` = `uppi`.`user_id` AND `uppi`.`ordering` = 1 
LEFT JOIN `#__user_profiles` AS uppi2 ON `u`.`id` = `uppi2`.`user_id` AND `uppi2`.`ordering` = 2
    ";
```

I've gone through the Joomla MVC tutorial and Lynda...neither one really addresses this beyond "here's some code - PLOP."

```
References:
    --//www.theartofjoomla.com/home/9-developer/135-database-upgrades-in-joomla-16.html
    --//stackoverflow.com/questions/8467858/joomla-1-7-db-query-does-not-work-when-query-has-an-ampersand
    --developer.joomla.org/standards/ch03s10.html
    --forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2506722
    --forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1200668
    --docs.joomla.org/API16:JDatabaseQuery
    --//fsadventures.com/2011/01/some-basic-joomla-database-call-functions/
    --//www.sourcecodester.com/php/3863/updating-multiple-rows-mysql-using-php.html
    --//stackoverflow.com/questions/7047471/mysql-query-syntax-error
```

**Questions:**

1)  Are there any differences between these?

2)  Is there a reason to use one method over another?

3)  Is there a good source for learning different ways of building these?  I've searched for hours and haven't found anything comprehensive.

Thanks!

Comment: Dont know about Joomla but in general i try never to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. I prefer to try a query and generate an Exception/error and then act on that error with a second query. Ive use quite a few different ORM and DBAL layers and none of them have ever supported that functionality from their API you usually have to revert to whatever raw SQL facilities they have to accomplish it.

Comment: Ahh, good point!  What I'm working on right now will never be used anywhere else but that's definitely something I'll keep in mine as I'm learning.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your type 1,2 & 3 are using the newer JDatabaseQuery object, whereas type 4 is using the older style to set the query to an SQL string.
2. If **type 4** isn't working do you get an SQL error? (Have you turned on Joomla's debug mode so you can get the SQL error dumped out with the app profile?)
3. JDatabaseQuery is used to provide the abstraction required to support multiple SQL databases rather than just mySQL, thats why the `$query` object has functions like `select()`,`where()`,`join()`, etc...
4. Remember that the `->leftJoin()` is a PHP call to the JDatabaseQuery function called `leftJoin()` and therefore must be one word ie. it can't be two.
5. `leftJoin()` actually just calls `join('LEFT',$conditions)` so it's a readability implementation more than a functional difference.
6. So, types 1,2 & 3 are effectively the same they're just have different degrees of readability (eg. IMHO type 2 & 3 are harder to read and maintain than type 1).

You seem to have found all the online sources for Joomla! documentation, apart from the Joomla! Google Groups ([CMS Dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/?#!forum/joomla-dev-cms), [General Dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/?#!forum/joomla-dev-general) and [Platform Dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/?#!forum/joomla-dev-platform)).

The only other source is Andrew Eddies "[Learn the Art of Joomla!](http://learn.theartofjoomla.com/)". I haven't used Andrew's stuff myself but I've heard lots of good things about it a the last Joomla! Day I attended.

**Edit**
Based on the error I would say it's because you have the identifier `u.id` encased as one identifier. Try something like:

```
SELECT `u`.`id` AS "UserID" FROM `#__users` AS `u`
```

Comment: Concerning 2) - Debugger says "JDatabaseMySQLi::query: 1054 - Unknown column 'u.id' in 'field list' ".  I probably don't have the right `` or '' - I saw a few different variations and wasn't sure what was correct.  But if that's outdated I won't even worry about it.

Comment: Awesome - that worked!  I didn't even think that could work, those little bits are totally tripping me up.  Thank you twice!